# Openldap passwords hashing with olcPasswordHash

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am tying to make openldap to store all `userPassword` attributes hashed with `{SSHA}` alogorithm. I managed to configure frontend db with **olcPasswordHash** :

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcFrontendConfig
olcDatabase: {-1}frontend
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20181218082812Z
olcPasswordHash: {SSHA}     <------------configured with ldapmodify
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
```

But even after slapd service restart new password modifications/creations (I use ldapvi to edit ldifs) are still in cleartext and nothing wrong in the ldap.log. Please note here that If I choose to write the password in encrypted format, (with {SSHA} tag in front) it is working normaly. The problem is that when I write it in cleartext it is not encrypted automaticaly after I save and exit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to let slapd generate a password hash from a clear-text *userPassword* value in a modify request then you have to configure [slapo-ppolicy](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy) with directive *ppolicy_hash_cleartext*.

Comment: Indeed! That solved the mistery :) Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This setting only applies when you're using the RFC 3062 extended operation, i.e. using `ldappasswd`. Just editing entries with normal LDIF operations won't work. If you want to seed entries with an encrypted value, use `slappasswd` to generate the hash.

**Edit:** Looking specifically at the [ldapvi documentation](http://www.lichteblau.com/ldapvi/manual/), it appears to use an LDIF-like format with some extensions. To get attributes encrypted, you need to specify the attribute using the form:

```
userPassword:ssha mysecret
```

I don't think the `olcPasswordHash` setting has any bearing on that functionality.

Comment: I can seed encrypted passwords without a problem. However I remember in the past using ldapvi in other ldap servers and even if I was writing in cleartext, after saving the ldif was automaticaly stored as encryped. Maybe there was a diffrent handling from ldapvi, I don't know. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: Yes I am aware of these extensions, but I remember the ldap I used in the past had no need of those in ldapvi.